# Rust discovery, config file not working as expected

Tags: rust, gdb, openocd, stm32ldiscovery, rustdoc

I am trying to avoid entering the same commands in each GDB sessions. For this, I have followed the instructions in [rust discovery book](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/discovery/05-led-roulette/the-challenge.html) but the program is not working as mentioned in the book when I run the program through cargo run it is giving the following error:

```
ts/project/discovery/src/06-hello-world$ cargo run
   error: could not load Cargo configuration
```

```
cargo run --target thumbv7em-none-eabihf
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.04s
     Running `arm-none-eabi-gdb -q -x openocd.gdb /home/jawwad-turabi/Documents/project/discovery/target/thumbv7em-none-eabihf/debug/led-roulette`
error: could not execute process `arm-none-eabi-gdb -q -x openocd.gdb /home/jawwad-turabi/Documents/project/discovery/target/thumbv7em-none-eabihf/debug/led-roulette` (never executed)

Caused by:
  No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

My openocd.gdb file contains these content:

```
   target remote: 3333
    load
    break main
    continue
```

My config file contain these content:

```
 [target.thumbv7em-none-eabihf]
   runner = "arm-none-eabi-gdb -q -x openocd.gdb"
   rustflags = [
   "-C", "link-arg=-Tlink.x",
   ]
   +[build]
   +target = "thumbv7em-none-eabihf"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please change runner = "arm-none-eabi-gdb -q -x openocd.gdb" to this
runner = "gdb-multiarch -q -x openocd.gdb".
Because, if you are using the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS version then this command will be used as the book mention.

Ubuntu 18.04 or newer / Debian stretch or newer

> NOTE *gdb-multiarch* is the GDB command you'll use to debug your ARM
>   Cortex-M programs

Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04

> NOTE *arm-none-eabi-gdb* is the GDB command you'll use to debug your ARM
>   Cortex-M programs

Answer (score 1):

While flashing the STM32F3, we have to connect to the respective GDB server. It may be **arm-none-eabi-gdb**, **gdb-multiarch** or **gdb**. You may have to try all the three.

Now, as far as your question is concerned, you have to use the same  parameter in your openocd.gdb. In my case, I have successfully tried with **arm-none-eabi-gdb**. Remember, I am using rust on Windows 10.